# Freeswitch ESL "cannot find -lesl"

Tags: c, freeswitch

I have written a simple ESL application in C. while compiling "ld" complains that it cannot find "-lesl":

> sudo gcc -o test_app main.c -lpthread -lm -lpq -lesl -L. -Isrc/include
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lesl
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I searched for "libesl.so" and could not find this. I am sure I missed out something while compiling Freeswitch. Can anyone please point out, what am I missing. Thank you.

Comment: ofcource I meant Freeswitch ESL

Comment: did you download the tarball from: <http://files.freeswitch.org/freeswitch-1.4.15.tar.bz2>?   Are you saying the tarball is missing the library?  According to your posted command line, your expecting the library to be in the same directory your compiling from. (a very unlikely situation)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. Yes I am using stable 1.4 branch from [stash](https://stash.freeswitch.org/scm/fs/freeswitch.git)  .. I think the compiled library is never a part of the tarball. It should work as long as the library is available in one of my available environment paths, IMHO.  I am following this documentation BTW [SangomaWiKi](http://wiki.sangoma.com/FreeSWITCH-ESL) . And if it helps, I am having my own codes under freeswitch/libs/esl where the example programs testserver.c and testclient.c also reside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved as follows:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl.c
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl_buffer.c    
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl_config.c
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl_event.c
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl_json.c
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall esl_threadmutex.c

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libesl.so.1 \
-o libesl.so.1.0.1 esl_buffer.o \
esl.o esl_config.o esl_event.o \
esl_json.o esl_threadmutex.o -lm
```

[-lm must be at the end of the line]

```
cp -p /usr/src/freeswitch/libs/esl/src/libesl.so.1.0.1 /usr/local/lib  
ln -s /usr/src/freeswitch/libs/esl/src/libesl.so.1.0.1 /usr/local  /lib/libesl.so.1
ln -s /usr/src/freeswitch/libs/esl/src/libesl.so.1 /usr/local/lib/libesl.so

echco '/usr/local/lib' > /etc/ld.conf.d/libesl.conf

run ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

step1:

```
cd ${freeswitch_code_path}/libs/esl && make
```

step2:

```
gcc -o test_app main.c ${freeswitch_code_path}/libs/esl/.libs/libesl.a -lpthread -lm -lpq  -Isrc/include
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer and adding a description to how your script solves the problem.